# Is Azure AD B2C FedRAMP authorized?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Azure AD is FedRAMP authorized on both Azure Government and Commercial Cloud. Does Azure AD B2C come under the same umbrella or its an independent service that need to be authorized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing this answer after receiving an update from the product group:

Azure AD B2C is not officially onboarded but is in the process of being onboarded and while we don’t have timelines, it is expected in the future.

Comment: If you checkout service description on this [website](https://marketplace.fedramp.gov/#/product/azure-commercial-cloud?sort=productName&status=Compliant), it doesn't mention Azure AD B2C. If you can clarify that for me, Thanks.

Comment: I believe that it's grouped in but I asked the Microsoft FedRAMP contacts to check. Will get back to you as soon as they reply.

Comment: I received an update from the product group. I will add the update to this thread. You were right to point out that they're not officially listed.

Comment: No problem, hope it helped.

Answer (score 2):

Azure AD B2C is now officially FedRAMP High compliant in the public cloud.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-government/compliance/azure-services-in-fedramp-auditscope